# Zapier Code: Python Http

Tags: python, zapier

I've got a simple python script that queries an API (using the `requests` library), parses the returned JSON, and builds a redirect URL based on the data returned from the API. The script works as a local python script run from my machine.

My goal is to have a URL that a user opens in their browser, which triggers the python code to run, build the redirect URL, and redirect the user to this new URL.

Can I use Zapier Webhooks + Zapier Code to achieve this?

The Python looks like this (details changed):

```
# A constant for the API query
query_str = "123"

# A constant in the redirect URL
resultant_constant = "93093"

# Personal Access Tokenfor this service
app_id = "the_app_id"
secret = "the_secret_key"

# Make API call and get a the JSON response
resp = requests.get('https://api.example.com/path/to/endpoint/'+ query_str +'/endpoint?filter=theFilter&order=sort_date', auth=(app_id,secret))

# Gets the id of the object I want 
my_id = resp.json()['data'][0]['id']

report_url = "https://subdomain.example.com/path/"+resultant_constant+".ext?&object_id="+my_id

return report_url
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have Zapier redirect a browser "GET" request to another URL. Zapier only accepts the data sent to it, and runs whatever actions you have set up in the zap behind-the-scenes.

However, minus the redirect, you can still achieve most of what you need:

Use the "Catch Raw Hook" option for a "GET" request that occurs when someone visits the URL provided by Zapier, IE: `https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/....`

Then, the "Code by Zapier" action allows you to run Python code.